# Connecting Hive and Oracle database using Sqoop

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, sqoop

Is it possible to export data from hive to Oracle DB using Sqoop for reporting purpose since i dont want to make any changes in client applications.

Regards,
Bhagwant Bhobe

Answer (score 2):

Use the [insert overwrite directory](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Writingdataintothefilesystemfromqueries) option with Hive for the output of the query to be written to a file and then use the Sqoop [export](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_export_literal) option to insert the data in the file into RDBMs. A work-flow using [Oozie](http://oozie.apache.org/) or [Azkaban](http://azkaban.github.io/azkaban2/) (does Azkaban supports Oozie and Hive tasks?) can also be used to automate this.

Answer (score 0):

By using sqoop export command you can export data from hive to oracle DB.

sqoop export --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@ipaddress:portnumber:DBName --table tableName --export-dir /user/hive/warehouse/emp1  --username uname --password pwd --fields-terminated-by '\001' -m 1

in --export-dir specify the location of hive output directory.